# How to keep changes in listview

Tags: android

I have a problem with a listview. I put 2 buttons in each item that changes a TextView.

When I change an item and makes scroll lose its contents because recycle the view.

How I can do to keep its content?

[image]

```
public class AdaptadorItemsMenu extends ArrayAdapter<MenuDet>{
ArrayList<MenuDet> list;
Activity context;
private Database db;
int numPlato;
public AdaptadorItemsMenu(Activity context, ArrayList<MenuDet> l, int numPlato) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_tab_menu , l);
    list = l;
    this.context = context;
    this.numPlato = numPlato;

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameProduct, numItems;
    Button deduct, add;
    LinearLayout linearMenuItem;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View item = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    MenuDet md = list.get(position);

    if(item == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_menu_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameProduct = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_name);
        holder.numItems = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.num_items);
        holder.deduct = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.button_deduct);
        holder.add = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        holder.linearMenuItem = (LinearLayout) item.findViewById(R.id.linearItemMenu);

        item.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
    }


    db = new Database(context, "NUMIER", null, Database.versionDB);

    String name = new ProductCrud(db).getNameProduct((md.getCode()));

    holder.nameProduct.setText(name);


    return(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite value of counter in DB in `OnClickListener` of your buttons plus and minus. ANd in `ViewHolder` just always `setText` to your `TextView` from DB.